# Flex Start Condition unexpected result

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have tired a very simple example using flex condition variable.

Base on my understanding, when I type "magic" as input, based on different condition, it should print out different string such as "first", "second"..

However, when I type magic, it only outputs "magic" which confuses me a lot.

```
%START AA BB CC
%%
^a                {ECHO; BEGIN AA;}
^b                {ECHO; BEGIN BB;}
^c                {ECHO; BEGIN CC;}
\n                {ECHO; BEGIN 0;}
<AA>magic         printf("first");
<BB>magic         printf("second");
<CC>magic         printf("third");
```

Comment: Remember that the default action, when no rule matches, is `ECHO`. Usually it's best to not use the default rule; in other words, ensure that every possible input matches something. Use the `--debug` or `-d` flag to get flex to show you what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

The input string should be "amagic\n"

instead of "a\n"->"magic\n"

Because every time the "\n" is entered, the flag is set to 0 again.